# How to do a count controlled loop without the count returning back to 0?

Tags: python, count, iteration, increment

So I have this section of code here:

```
count = 1
if count < 5:
      print ("If 5 rounds have passed, enter any other key: ")
      nextr = str(input("Do you want to continue to the next round?(1)" + "\n"))
      if nextr in ("1", "(1)"):
            count += 1
            continue
      while count == 5:
          break
```

And I wondered: How could I do this count controlled loop without it reverting back to 1 every time. I would like the program to go through a game once, ask the user if they want to continue, then go through it 4 more times before breaking and then showing the final scores. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are completely messed with loop and conditional statement. Think about what this is doing: `while count == 5: break`.

Comment: Do you mean `if count < 5:` transformed to `while count < 5:`?

Comment: Input is already a string, you don't need to parse `str(input[...]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you looking for, but it may help.

```
print ("If 5 rounds have passed, enter any other key")
count = 1
while count <= 5:    
    nextr = (input("Do you want to continue to the next round?(Yes/No)"))
    print ("count = ",count)
    if nextr.lower() in ("y", "yes"):
        count += 1
```

Or maybe something like this one:

```
import time

def round_5():
    count = 1
    while count <= 5:
        print ("Count = ",count)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
nextr = "y"
print ("If 5 rounds have passed, enter any other key:")
while nextr.lower() in ("yes","y"): 
    round_5()
    nextr = (input("Do you want to continue to the next round?(Yes/No)"))
print ("Thank you, have a nice day")
```

Comment: Those `continue` and `break` are totally unnecessary.

Comment: What I would like to know is: Looping through the program once gives a count of 1. Once the user enters (1) to continue to the next round it loops through that round. However , at the end of that round, it changes the count back to 1, which doesn't ever stop the program.

Comment: @Austin Yes, you're right. I just follow the code by Oliver.

Comment: @Oliver What should be the first input of your program? Especially for the question of `Do you want to continue to the next round?(1)`

Comment: The input would be 1 or (1) to continue, but considering to change it to "Yes", so it's less confusing.

Comment: So, do you need to enter `1` or `(1)` every time to continue the program until it reaches `5`? And the program should stop after 5? What if you enter other than `1` or `(1)`, for example `2`?